# Check query string (or maybe not a query string) to see if value equals

Tags: c#, request.querystring

I have the following URL:

```
http://testexample.htm#tab=matchup&schoolid=74c1621c-e0cf-4821-b5e1-3c8170c8125a
```

In my code, I want to check to see if "tab" equals "matchup" in the URL

```
if (Request.QueryString["tab"] == "matchup")
{
    VideoPlayerUserControl.Settings.AutoStart = On;
}
```

This code doesn't seem to work.. is that because "tab" has a preceding hash (#)?

Comment: That's not a query string. Query string is what goes after `?`. What you are referring to is not sent to the server, it's a client-side value

Comment: Correct.  Values after the hash are not sent to the server.  Those are used client-side only.

Comment: ok thanks. So I probaly need javascript for this then